# Changing angular material date picker date format on run time

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have app wide default date format for angular material date picker i.e. dd/mm/yyyy and I have common a date picker component which I reused in different places. In couple of places, I need the date picker date format to be dd/mm/yy. I do not want to create another common date picker component only for different date format. I want to pass a format using @input() and date picker will change the format accordingly. Looks like angular material does not have any thing to do that.

Any one have any solution for that?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can try working with Angular DatePipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Angular Material doesn't allow you to work with a Pipe in the display value.